# Minimizing distance between vectors using only the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am working on a project (not homework) that requires me to optimize the distance between two vectors, but I only have access to a dot product, not the individual elements of the vectors. I can easily perform a numerical optimization and minimize the quantity:

$$ d = \lvert x - y \rvert^2 = \langle x, x \rangle - 2 \langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle $$

The problem I encounter with this approach is that, no matter how small $d$ becomes, I find that, after optimization, $ q^T A x \neq q^T A y $ for some operator $A$ and vector $q$ which are constant. For this to work, I would need $ q^T A x = q^T A y $ for *all* operators $A$, which (I think?) should be the case if the vectors are identical -- but again, I can only take inner products to verify.

Can this optimization problem be solved uniquely? Are there other "mathematical debugging" steps I can take? I am not a mathematician, so I really appreciate answers at an advanced undergrad core math level.

Comment: Just for clarification, is $y$ fixed and $x$ variable? If so, isn't the minimization of $d$ zero, by taking $x=y$?

Comment: Great question, @Chrystomath. $x$ is fixed and $y$ is variable, _but_ the vectors have different underlying structures, and so $x = y$ is actually nontrivial.

Comment: Maybe nontrivial, but that's the minimum. I'm guessing you have some algorithm which changes $y$ to minimise $d$. It is approaching $x$ (whose coefficients you don't know), but because it hasn't reached it yet, $q^TAx\ne q^TAy$, but the difference is probably small.

Comment: @Chrystomath The difference between $q^T A x$ and $q^T A y$ is actually not small at all... even when I measure $d^2 \approx 10^{-5}$, which is where the optimizer tends to get stuck. So do you think it's more likely a problem with the way I am optimizing and not the math?

Comment: Yes. The algorithm needs to take smaller steps as it approaches the minimum. Otherwise it keeps jumping around the minimum.